# autocomplete freeze when making searchs too fast

Tags: android, web-services, autocomplete

I have the next code to make search of artist and songs on the spotify servers. I have an autocomplete text but my problem is if I search for something, like "David Guetta" and I try to delete with backspace ( <-- ) everytime that I delete one character it makes a search, and if I do it so fast the app crashes (heavy usage?). I don't know really if it is for that question.

What can I do to fix this? With a wait time to search it can be fixed but I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

This is my SearchMusic.java code.

```
public class SearchMusic extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteSongs;
    String searchTerms;
    String[] arrayArtist = new String[64];
    String[] arrayTrack = new String[64];
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> songs;
    List<String> lArtist;
    List<String> lTrack;

    boolean bothsearchs = false; // Controlamos que haya busqueda por artista y
                                    // pista si uno no existe.

    int nArtist = 0; // iterator

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_music);

        autoCompleteSongs = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompletePetition);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        // autoCompleteSongs.setThreshold(1);
        // autoCompleteSongs.addTextChangedListener(this);
        // autoCompleteSongs.setAdapter(new
        // ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        // item));

        autoCompleteSongs.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                if (s.length() > 3) {
                    searchTerms = s.toString();
                    searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(" ", "+");
                    // Buscamos por artista
                    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                    client.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json?q="
                            + searchTerms + "*", null,
                            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                                public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
                                    try {
                                        // Hay artistas con ese nombre
                                        if (data.length() > 0) {
                                            JSONArray artist = new JSONArray(
                                                    data.getJSONArray("artists")
                                                            .toString());

                                            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                                                JSONObject orden = artist
                                                        .getJSONObject(i);
                                                String name = orden
                                                        .getString("name");
                                                list.add(name);
                                                arrayArtist[i] = name;
                                                arrayTrack[i] = "";
                                                nArtist++;
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            bothsearchs = true;
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {

                                }
                            });

                    // Buscamos por pista
                    client.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q="
                            + searchTerms + "*", null,
                            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                                public void onSuccess(JSONObject spoty) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONArray artist = new JSONArray(spoty
                                                .getJSONArray("tracks")
                                                .toString());

                                        for (int i = nArtist; i < nArtist + 6 ; i++) {
                                            JSONObject orden = artist
                                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                                            String name = orden
                                                    .getString("name");
                                            JSONArray nameArtist = new JSONArray(
                                                    orden.getJSONArray(
                                                            "artists")
                                                            .toString());
                                            JSONObject namArt = nameArtist
                                                    .getJSONObject(0);
                                            String nameArt = namArt
                                                    .getString("name");

                                            list.add("[" + nameArt + "] "
                                                    + name);
                                            arrayArtist[i] = nameArt;
                                            arrayTrack[i] = name;
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
                                }

                            });

                    list.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.petitionTextView);

                    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                        Log.i("AART", "" + arrayArtist[i]);
                        Log.i("ATRA", "" + arrayTrack[i]);
                        }

                    if(arrayArtist[0] == null && arrayTrack[0] == ""){
                        text.setText("No hay resultados");
                    }else{

                        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                            String register = "<font color=#64c7eb>" + arrayArtist[i] + "</font> <font color=#272527>" + arrayTrack[i] + "</font></br>";
                            text.setText(Html.fromHtml(register));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_music, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

If I am right, this the code that I need. The problem is how to stop it. ¬¬

```
//Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already giving a good solution.
Try wrapping the http request within a TimerTask and create a timer mechanism to cancel out the TimerTask.

Example (not tested):

```
public class SearchMusic extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteSongs;
    String searchTerms;
    String[] arrayArtist = new String[64];
    String[] arrayTrack = new String[64];
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> songs;
    List<String> lArtist;
    List<String> lTrack;
    //Declare and initialize the timer
    Timer t = new Timer();

    boolean bothsearchs = false; // Controlamos que haya busqueda por artista y
                                    // pista si uno no existe.

    int nArtist = 0; // iterator

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_music);

        autoCompleteSongs = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompletePetition);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        // autoCompleteSongs.setThreshold(1);
        // autoCompleteSongs.addTextChangedListener(this);
        // autoCompleteSongs.setAdapter(new
        // ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        // item));

        autoCompleteSongs.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                if (s.length() > 3) {

                    // Cancel the Timer and all scheduled tasks
                    t.cancel();
                    t.purge();
                    t = new Timer();

                    //Set the schedule function and rate
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
                            searchTerms = s.toString();
                            searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(" ", "+");
                            // Buscamos por artista
                            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                            client.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json?q="
                                    + searchTerms + "*", null,
                                    new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                                        public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
                                            try {
                                                // Hay artistas con ese nombre
                                                if (data.length() > 0) {
                                                    JSONArray artist = new JSONArray(
                                                            data.getJSONArray("artists")
                                                                    .toString());

                                                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                                                        JSONObject orden = artist
                                                                .getJSONObject(i);
                                                        String name = orden
                                                                .getString("name");
                                                        list.add(name);
                                                        arrayArtist[i] = name;
                                                        arrayTrack[i] = "";
                                                        nArtist++;
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    bothsearchs = true;
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {

                                        }
                                    });

                            // Buscamos por pista
                            client.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q="
                                    + searchTerms + "*", null,
                                    new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                                        public void onSuccess(JSONObject spoty) {
                                            try {
                                                JSONArray artist = new JSONArray(spoty
                                                        .getJSONArray("tracks")
                                                        .toString());

                                                for (int i = nArtist; i < nArtist + 6 ; i++) {
                                                    JSONObject orden = artist
                                                            .getJSONObject(i);
                                                    String name = orden
                                                            .getString("name");
                                                    JSONArray nameArtist = new JSONArray(
                                                            orden.getJSONArray(
                                                                    "artists")
                                                                    .toString());
                                                    JSONObject namArt = nameArtist
                                                            .getJSONObject(0);
                                                    String nameArt = namArt
                                                            .getString("name");

                                                    list.add("[" + nameArt + "] "
                                                            + name);
                                                    arrayArtist[i] = nameArt;
                                                    arrayTrack[i] = name;
                                                }

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
                                        }

                                    });

                            list.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.petitionTextView);

                            for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                                Log.i("AART", "" + arrayArtist[i]);
                                Log.i("ATRA", "" + arrayTrack[i]);
                                }

                            if(arrayArtist[0] == null && arrayTrack[0] == ""){
                                text.setText("No hay resultados");
                            }else{

                                for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                                    String register = "<font color=#64c7eb>" + arrayArtist[i] + "</font> <font color=#272527>" + arrayTrack[i] + "</font></br>";
                                    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(register));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
                    0,
                    //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
                    1000);

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_music, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, at this moment, I know what to do (create a tasktimer) but I don't know how to stop it. I paste code under the first comment.

Comment: I'm talking about my code, how to use it an stop it in my code, inside the onTextChanged Method.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try those two methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is using a handler, this is a simple example with a button. But the button represents the backspace on your code.

The idea is to schedule the search action within 500 miliseconds but when someone hits the search button again, we reschedule the search action until the user stops hitting the search button.

Good luck!

```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
        protected static final int MSG_SEARCH = 0;

        protected Button buttonSearch;

        protected Handler handler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
            {
                switch (msg.what)
                {
                    case MSG_SEARCH:

                        MyActivity.this.search();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onClick(View inView)
        {
            if (inView == this.buttonSearch)
            {
                this.handler.removeMessages(MSG_SEARCH);
                final Message message = Message.obtain(this.handler, MSG_SEARCH);
                this.handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 500);
            }
        }

        protected void search()
        {
            // your seach code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was using GooglePlaceApi to get list of addresses. I used synchronized in the performFiltering(), publishResults() and also the method that does the rest call. It worked for me. Maybe you can give a try.

```
 synchronized (input)
  {
   // Do something inside
  }
```